# Java program only writing last line?

Tags: java, writer

My issue is that with the reader the writer is only outputting what is on the last line of the file and I'm not sure why as far as I know I'm not accidentally closing it or any error similar to that. This is the code I'm using for the writer

```
private static void processhtml(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

    //splits the file at colons
    int count=0;
    String line="";
    String[] words=new String[40];
    try{
        String fileName="test"+count+".html";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
             line =s.nextLine();
             words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");

             for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                 writer.println(words[i]);
             }

             writer.close();
             writer.flush();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample snippet of your input file?  That combined with your regex might hold some bearing on the answer to this question.

Comment: 1. You must `flush()` and _then_ `close()` and do it _outside_ the loop. 2. [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) allows you not to be concerned about that. `try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8")) { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're creating your Writer outside the loop, but then closing it from within the loop.  Are you sure it's only the last line you're getting?  My guess would be you're only getting the first line.

It seems like this needs to move after the next curly brace:

```
        writer.close();
        writer.flush();
```

And you should probably switch the ordering since `flush()` won't do anything if the stream is already closed (though often `close()` calls `flush()` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your writer too early.

```
private static void processhtml(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

    //splits the file at colons
    int count=0;
    String line="";
    String[] words=new String[40];
    try{
        String fileName="test"+count+".html";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            line =s.nextLine();
            words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");

            for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                writer.println(words[i]);
            }

            /////////////////////////
            // closing writer within loop on first iteration
            writer.close();
            writer.flush();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
private static void processhtml(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

    //splits the file at colons
    int count=0;
    String line="";
    String[] words=new String[40];
    try{
        String fileName="test"+count+".html";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            line =s.nextLine();
            words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");

            for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                writer.println(words[i]);
            }

            writer.flush();
        }
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```